# Converting an object in an array to just an object ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, api, object

Here is the received response from API:

```
[{id:3, name: John-Doe, age: 30}]
```

the problem is I need to map through this array to use it:

```
  <>
        {movie.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <h1>{item.name}</h1>
              <p>{item.age}</p>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </>
```

I don't want to use map, since there will always be the details of just one person in the API's response (only a one-element array). I want to get rid of the array and convert it to an object so that I can use it directly like {item.age} without using map which doesn't make sense for an array with one element.

Comment: So just use `movie[0]?.name`. Or go to the place where you are setting this state variable and change it to `setMovie(moviesDataYouGot[0]);`.

Comment: what is the difference between movie[0]?.name and movie[0].name  ?

Comment: `undefined?.name` will return `undefined`, `undefined.name` will throw an exception "Cannot read properties of undefined". So if your data array is 0 sized by some way - you will not get an exception. [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: @SergeySosunov: Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also destructure the array:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [movie] = [{ id: 3, name: John - Doe, age: 30 }];

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{movie.name}</h1>
      <p>{movie.age}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1 -** You can access the values directly like this  :

```
function Test() {
  const movie = [{ id: 3, name: 'John - Doe', age: 30 }];

  return (
    <>
      <h1>movie[0].name</h1>
      <p>{movie[0].age}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

**2 -** Or extract the object inside movie array and store it in a variable  like this :

```
function Test() {
  const movie = [{ id: 3, name: 'John - Doe', age: 30 }];
  const movieObj = movie[0]

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{movieObj.name}</h1>
      <p>{movieObj.age}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```